# Silverlight TextBlockcutting off text?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have the following setup

```
<grid>
  <StackPanel>
    <ListBox>
      <TextBlock> ->Text you see getting cutt off<-
```

I have tried both just doing listbox.Add(String) and dynamically creating a TextBlock, assigning it text and then adding it to the listbox. Both produce identical results.

The image shows the listbox scrolled down half wayish. It appears the listbox has the correct height but the text inside hits some kind of limit.

[image]

### UPDATE I changed the listbox to a scroll viewer and also hardcoded the Textblock in. Still same exact results

```
 <Grid x:Name="theGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,10,0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Networking Tools" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stack">
                <TextBlock x:Name="inputIndicator" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                    <Run Text="Enter IP OR Domain"/>
                </TextBlock>
                <telerikPrimitives:RadTextBox x:Name="input" Text="google.com" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Height="84" Width="458"/>
                <telerikInput:RadListPicker SelectionChanged="picker_SelectionChanged" x:Name="picker" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436"/>
                <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>
                <ScrollViewer  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="392" Width="Auto" x:Name="list" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock Name="content" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
                </ScrollViewer>

            </StackPanel>
            <UI:AdControl ApplicationId="test_client" AdUnitId="Image480_80" Height="80" Width="480"/>

        </StackPanel>
        <telerikPrimitives:RadBusyIndicator Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="106" Width="116" AnimationStyle="AnimationStyle1" x:Name="busyIndi" />
      </Grid>
```

Comment: Are you adding a `TextBox` or a `TextBlock`?  It looks like your text is cut off both horizontally and vertically - is this true, or did you just black some of it out?  Can you post some more detailed XAML - there's not enough to go on here

Comment: @RobSiklos It was a typo. you are correct its a TextBlock

Comment: Can you show your code for the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox` ?

Comment: @NeilTurner there you go. Thanks for looking

Comment: Instead of the root `Grid` containing a `StackPanel`, you could try laying out the inner elements with `RowDefinitions` & 'Grid.Row', the default template's MainPage.xaml does this, for example.

Comment: @NeilTurner Yeah I had that in there and it was the same result. I removed it thinking it may be the problem

Comment: How about trying different values for `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` with the `TextBlock` in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI elements in Windows Phone 7 have a maximum renderable height and width of 2048 pixels.  Any content that is larger than that gets clipped.  The limit is only slightly higher for Windows Phone 8.

You did not mention how much text you are trying to show, but if it is very long, you could be hitting that limit.

There are a few ways you could handle this:

1) Break the text into smaller chunks and add individual TextBlocks to your StackPanel for each chunk.

2) Create a custom control that does the above for you, like this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx

3) Use a WebBrowser control instead of a TextBlock, and use its NavigateToString method to put your text in there.

Comment: I didn't want to wait for an answer to I opted for option 1 lol. It was to easy to just say if the length was greater than X then break it up. Thanks for the info, I didn't know that!